# How do you create a query that will result with the adjacent parcels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, query, parcel, spatial-query

I have a shapefile with parcel data, and I am trying to create a query that will render a list or something similar that will list adjacent parcels to a specific parcel.

I want to be able to select the my parcel and the query to result with all the adjacent property owners.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Can you make another edit to make it clear whether you are just talking about a polygon shapefile or an actual parcel fabric, please?

Comment: An alternative approach may be to use Polygon Neighbors to update a field on each parcel with a list of identifiers representing its neighbours - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80363/adding-updating-field-to-polygon-feature-class-that-lists-bordering-neighbor-p/80364#80364

Answer (score 2):

The simple way would be to use [Select Layer by Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000) to select the focused parcel, then use [Select Layer By Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000072000000) using *"share a line segment with the source layer feature"* as the spatial selection method, see caption below:

[image]

This method may then be incorporated into a Model or saved and wrapped around a python script to generate a table export or custom report.

Comment: You may want to look through the options under the *Spatial selection method for target layer features(s)* for other options you want to try out.  For example...If you are trying to select nearby parcels that may be across a street, they won't share a line segment so you may need to look at other options like a small distance calculation.